# Python unit test, run some methods only once

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am using Django testcase for one testsuit like this:

```
class XXXTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ....

    def test_something(self):
        ....

    def test_anthoerthing(self):
        ....
```

Now I notice that there are a lot of things repeated in `test_something()` and `test_anotherthing()` (mostly running some method and get the returned value).

Is there any way I can only run the repeated part once for the testsuit?

Comment: You probably want [Class and Module Fixtures](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Peter mentioned, you want to refer to the Python documentation on this one, since Django's `django.test.TestCase` is a subclass of Python's `unittest.TestCase` ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/)).

The part that literally does what you want in your specific example, vs. `setUp` which works on a method level, is `setUpClass`.

Usage, from Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass), is here:

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls._connection = createExpensiveConnectionObject()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls._connection.destroy()
```

If you have multiple `TestCases` in your module that also share code, take a look at `setUpModule`, which is similar but operates at a (as you'd expect) module level.

So, `setUp` (method) < `setUpClass` (class) < `setUpModule` (module), in terms of levels of test fixtures/setup.

Comment: I would add that you'll want to make sure that the code you use to dry those up should not store off any values that ever get changed by tests. If you change the value in one test, you change it for other tests that need to access that data, and you end up creating dependencies between your tests, such that they no longer test against the same initial data.
If the data does need to change, you can still dry it up in the setUp method for the sake of readability, but then you don't get the same performance benefit that you do from using setUpClass or setUpModule.